# Pass variable from client to server-side in NEXTJS

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, client-side

I have already done this but Idk why when I try to apply it again in another code it does not work. So I have this code "Client side"

```js
const response = await fetch("/api/ipfs", {method: "POST", DATA: "holaaaa"});
if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Error: ${response.status}`);
}
const result = await response.json()
console.log(result.result)
```

And this one that is the "Server side"

```js
function uploadIPFS(req, res) {
  axios.get(req.body).then(r => {
  
    let metadata = r.data

    res.status(200).json({ metadata: metadata });
  }).catch(err => console.error(err))
}

export default function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method==='POST') {
      uploadIPFS(req, res);
  }
}
```

This is working with another api file I have, so I implement another file that is this one and in another function of the client side make a call to the new api file, the problem is that the variable I want to pass from client to server is the body one, the one that says "holaaaa", is it not working and it throws this error.

```
    API resolved without sending a response for /api/ipfs, this may result in stalled requests.
Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'replace')
    at dispatchHttpRequest (C:\Users\berna\Desktop\Programming\Web development\BlueToken\bluetoken\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:161:23)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at httpAdapter (C:\Users\berna\Desktop\Programming\Web development\BlueToken\bluetoken\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:49:10) 
    at dispatchRequest (C:\Users\berna\Desktop\Programming\Web development\BlueToken\bluetoken\node_modules\axios\lib\core\dispatchRequest.js:58:10)
    at Axios.request (C:\Users\berna\Desktop\Programming\Web development\BlueToken\bluetoken\node_modules\axios\lib\core\Axios.js:109:15) 
    at Axios.<computed> [as get] (C:\Users\berna\Desktop\Programming\Web development\BlueToken\bluetoken\node_modules\axios\lib\core\Axios.js:131:17)
    at Function.wrap [as get] (C:\Users\berna\Desktop\Programming\Web development\BlueToken\bluetoken\node_modules\axios\lib\helpers\bind.js:9:15)
    at uploadIPFS (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/ipfs.js:17:11)
    at handler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/ipfs.js:37:9)
    at Object.apiResolver (C:\Users\berna\Desktop\Programming\Web development\BlueToken\bluetoken\node_modules\next\dist\server\api-utils\node.js:184:15) {
config: {
    transitional: {
    silentJSONParsing: true,
    forcedJSONParsing: true,
    clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'User-Agent': 'axios/0.27.2'
    },
    method: 'get',
    url: '',
    data: undefined
},
url: '',
exists: true
}
```

any idea abt this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request to your API is made, but you are not adding anything to the request body. I think you need to change your `DATA` property in your fetch call to `body`:

```js
const response = await fetch("/api/ipfs", { method: "POST", body: "holaaaa" });
```

Also, since you are passing that body parameter to the `axios.get()` method in your API handler, I assume it's supposed to be a URL?

Comment: should I do only req.body without axios?

Comment: sorry @bernardoolisan but it's hard to give specific advice without understand more about what you are trying to achieve

Comment: it works, but, is there a way to pass in the "body" a base64 data? bc is saying this `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')` any idea?